# WPF: set GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle code behind

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, styles

So i have my `ListView` and `GridView` inside `ListView.View`:

```
<GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderDefaultStyle}" >
```

And i Added several `Styles` that i am want to change via code behind.
but all found is how to change `ItemContainerStyle`

Answer (score 1):

Just give your `GridView` an `x:Name` in your XAML:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="gv">
          ...
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

...and you will be able to access it in the code-behind as usual:

```
gv.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle = this.FindResource("ListViewHeaderDefaultStyle") as Style;
```